# Use Python need to remove the هههههههه that exceed 3 ه

Tags: python, nlp, arabic, preprocessor

How to remove the extra 'ه' in the word?
Maximum 3 'ه' in the word

> شنو هل الغابة اوي عايشين بيها كلنا نختلف ههههههههههههه اي اي الايلينز تجين

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit tricky because of the right-to-left orientation but this seems to work for me:

```
import re

text = "شنو هل الغابة اوي عايشين بيها كلنا نختلف ههههههههههههه اي اي الايلينز تجين"
text = re.sub("ه{3,}", "ههه", text)
print(text)
> "شنو هل الغابة اوي عايشين بيها كلنا نختلف ههه اي اي الايلينز تجين"
```

But if I understand Google Translator right the repeated part is just laughing, so not sure how much value you get from unifying that for NLP purposes.

Comment: Thank you so much it work with me fine. Yes I needed for NLP